# Nested elements mouseover, how to not repeat the children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to triggers an event only if my mouse is over a specific div.

For some reason the code is repeated in proportion of the seconds passed over the div. 
Is it a way to avoid this behavior ? I want my code to be execute only once.

Here is my code

```
$('.user-notation-block-online').on({mouseover: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = $(this).attr('data-comment');let regex = /\d+/;let match = target.match(regex);let uniqueId = match[0];

    $('#js-action-edit-' + uniqueId).click(function (e) {
        let $textareaContent =  $("#js-content-comment-" + uniqueId)
        let $titleContent = $('#js-content-title-'+uniqueId)
        let exValue = $textareaContent.text().trim()
        let exTitle = $titleContent.text().trim()
        textAreaContentInitial = exValue;
        titleContentInitial = exTitle;

        $('#js-user-block-' + uniqueId).prepend('<h1 class="edit-header" id="edition-header-' + uniqueId + '">Formulaire d\'édition</h1>')
        $('#js-action-block-' + uniqueId).html('')
        $('#js-button-block-' + uniqueId).prepend('<button class="btn-primary btn user-save" id="js-action-save-' + comment.uniqueId + '">Sauvegarder</button>\n' +
            '<button class="btn-danger btn user-save" id="js-action-cancel-'+ uniqueId +'">Anuler</button>')
        $textareaContent.replaceWith('<textarea class="edit-text-area">' + exValue + '</textarea>')
        $titleContent.replaceWith('<input class="edit-input-title" type="text" value="' + exTitle + '">');
    })
}})
```

Comment: [`one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) ?

Comment: A working example would be helpful.  You can do that easily inside of SO using the [JS snippet feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: DontVoteMeDown thanks you a lot you solve my problem with 4 letters <3